# How to check that an auction is finished - Triggered PHP processing

Tags: php, sql

I have a few ideas about this but here is what I need to do and just wanted some second opinions really.

I am writing a small auction site in PHP/SQL, but I have come up against a hurdle.

When an item finishes, much like eBay, I need to be able to tell that it's finished and send out the emails to who has won it and who has sold it.

The only way I can think of is to schedule a piece of code to keep checking what auctions have ended but surely there is a better way?

Comment: I assume you're hoping for some kind of listener... I'm not aware of any, and would just schedule a check every minute, but... I'm not confident enough in my answer to put it as an "answer".

Comment: Doesn't eBay already send this information?

Comment: It is correct its a kind of listener that i need... but i can't run it every 1 minute as thats too slow, as someone might pay straight away... if the site gets 1000's of auctions running it every 10 seconds won't work as the script might take 60 seconds to run

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triggered PHP processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979043/triggered-php-processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be kind to share the SQL script that query the highest bidder based on the bidding end date (how to know the bidding is over) and award the product to the highest bidder

Answer (score 5):

The solution can be in multiple parts :

- **A script** that is launched via **Cron** (every 5 minutes could be good, even less...). It detects the finished auction and **put them in a queue**.
- **A script**, that pretty much **runs continuously**, and that **processes items in the queue**.

Note that :

- You have to ensure that an auction is still open before displaying the page ! (a simple test) That way people can't join in after it closes.
- For each script, you can use PHP, or any other language

**Advantages** :

- The cron job is very fast, low on resources, and if there are a lot of auction to process, there is no risk it will be run in parallel (and then conflicts)
- The queue system ensure that your system won't crash because there is too much going on... It will process the queue as fast as possible, but if it is not fast enough, the website will continue to run. You can however end up with emails being sent hours or days after the auction is closed. But the "limit" is way more predictible, and won't crash your system.
- You can extend it in the future with multithreading processing of the queue, distributed processing... This is a scalable architecture.
- This architecture is fun.

*Additionnal informations :*

- Regarding the daemon script, I doesn't have to run continuously. What you can do is : at the end of the cron job, if there are items in the queue, then it checks if the other script (processing) is running. If yes then exit. If the other script is not running, it launches it...
- The daemon script gets an item out of the queue and process it. At the end, if there are still items in the queue, it processes it, else, it exits.
- With this system, everything is optimal and everyone loves each other !

To check if the other script is running, you can use a file and write in it "1" or "0" (= running / not running). The first script reads it, the second writes it... You can also use the database to do it. Or you can maybe use system tools or shell command...

Comment: It is correct its a kind of listener that i need... but i can't run it every 1 minute as thats too slow, as someone might pay straight away... if the site gets 1000's of auctions running it every 10 seconds won't work as the script might take 60 seconds to run

Comment: No, did you read my answer ? On the website, you need to check if the auction is finished. If it is, you can't allow any action on it. The processing (deciding who won, sending emails, processing payments...) is done asynchronously, in background. And 1000 auctions will be processed one at a time in background, it won't slow down your website. **I don't understand where you see a problem**.

Comment: I see the problem in the fact if the script takes 60 seconds to do them 1000, what happens to the 1000 that finish in that 60 seconds ???

Comment: @Lee Well the emails of the 1000th auction will be sent after 60 seconds, but the web page will be updated instantly ! (because you always check if the auction is closed in the web page) **Is that a problem ?** If you need you emails to be sent instantly, then the problem is with the performances of your machines. I think this is a good architecture possible regarding scalability. If you need *real time*, then you need a lot of money

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli This is really a clever solution. I was thinking of using a MySQL trigger to insert a row into a 'auction-complete' table which would also need a cron-job to check it every couple seconds. This is a much cleaner and more scalable solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a cron job to run every 10-20-30-60 minutes etc to send out emails and update the auction details.

If you're script is fast, running it every minute or so may be alright.

Be aware that many shared hosting will only allow you to send out a certain number of emails per hour.

Do these emails need to be sent out instantly?,

Comment: How does this solve the problem if he wants the site to update the auction as "ended" on the site?

Comment: The script will update the DB as well as sending emails. When the script finds finished auctions it will update the auction to "ended". The front end will obviously need to be refreshed to see the result but it will be automated.

Comment: You could use ajax to poll the db in the background if you think people are just staring at the auction waiting for it to say "ended". So you could get ajax to help you determine the auction end, action email sending and other auction updates.

Comment: I think you should add this to your answer as well, as it was not clear that the script would update the db as well. I am thinking why use cron and Ajax for this, when you could as well just use Ajax alone.

Comment: I am thinking along the line of: once auction is started, db is updated with end_time. Then Ajax will be used to check if current_time == end_time to decide whether to end the auction or not

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to use both cron and ajax - one or the other.

Comment: It is correct its a kind of listener that i need... but i can't run it every 1 minute as thats too slow, as someone might pay straight away... if the site gets 1000's of auctions running it every 10 seconds won't work as the script might take 60 seconds to run

Comment: We didn't suggest running a script every 10 seconds - I said every 5 minutes or more.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 possible problems and goals you are trying to achive:

- **Visual**: You want that when a user browse your website, without updating or refreshing the page, it keeps updating the page so that if an audition ends, it appears something like "Audition ended, the item goes to...". 
  **Solution**: You should use Javascript and AJAX. (I assume you are already using it for countdowns or something). Make an AJAX call every 5 seconds (could be enough) and update the content.
- **Pratical**: You want that if an audition is ended an user cannot join it. **Solution:** You can do it just with PHP and mysql. You could create a fields where you store the audition start timestamp and then make a simple `if (time() >= ($timestamp + $duration)) {}` (where `$timestamp` is the start of the audition and `$duration` is the duration of the audition) to block possible bad users trying to do it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, it's about a listener that is called when an auction is finished => a piece of code launched at a particular date and time.

Comment: @Matthieu, that falls in the first possible problem. You have to use AJAX and Javascript for that. You have to look for the start of the audition and then keep checking on background what time is it and if the audition has anded.

Comment: @Charliepiga No he's talking server side, processing auction... What if nobody visits the page of the auction will it finishes. It won't be processed.

Comment: @Matthieu, yep. It will end. If nobody visit the page why do we care then? The audition will end anyway, because if it ends while nobody is watching nothing happen, but if a user visit the page after that he will se "Audition ended". Why do we care if nobody watch?

Comment: @Chariepiga if nobody visits the page, them when/how is the email sent ?