# Triggered PHP processing

Tags: php, sql, triggers

I ask a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5964407/2246380) yesterday but it all got confusing and I thought I would start again and try and explain it a bit better..

I am about to design an auction site, much the same as ebay... items start from 24,12,7,3,1 days and count down until they are finished..

Now its easy for the page that shows the item to know its finished via ajax/jquery BUT, i presume i would need to run some sort of scheduled script that checks when auctions have finished.

This script will need to convert the auction in the database to finished so that in the sellers profile they can see its finished and the buyer can pay.

The trouble is if a script runs every 5 minutes, it means it could take up to 5 minutes for the auction to appear as finished in the sellers profile area, which is naff.

Also the Buyer wouldn't be able to pay until its converted over...

However if I were to run a script every 30-60 seconds surely this will be too much load on the server as the script may run multiple times if it has many auctions to convert and it takes more than 30-60 seconds to run ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that a scheduled script is the solution you are looking for. You could set the auction status when you display it to a user - being that on auctioner's profile, or in auctions list or anywhere else . This way, you are guaranteed that who sees the auction, is seeing it with the status from when the page was loaded.
Anyway, having a scheduled script to update the status is recommended only when you have heavy business logic to be done when an auction expired

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to run a script on the back-end to know if the auction has finished. All you have to do is store a timestamp of the end date/time and compare to that to get the status.

You might still want a daemon style script that processes the auctions and does what it needs to at regular interval but this should not dictate any of the front-end logic.

So on the front-end, you just have some JS (Timed Ajax, Comet, or any of the similar...) that queries the server whether the end timestamp has been reached or not (and possibly get a countdown time left, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an end date(time) in your DB, then you can simply search for items where that date is either in the past or future depending upon you requirements. There is no need to set anything to "finished", per se. On a user's "My Ebay" page you could style the items differently depending upon their status (which side of the date they are).

Similarly, bidding could only take place on items "in-date" etc.